# In Python how can I decompile something which compiled with compile() function?

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, decompiling

Here is my code

```
script = """
a = 10
b = 20
print ('addition = ',a+b)
"""
code = compile(script, "script", "exec")
```

This compile() function will return a code object. But I want to know how can I reverse it?  In some blog i hear that it can be decompile with [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/). But what is the process to decompile it? Or is there any other module to do so?

---

- *Note: Please Don't suggest me use [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module and reconstruct the
  source-code*

---

Comment: why? this is an unusual task

Comment: for learning purpose

Answer (score 0):

The decompilation process works similar to the compilation process. In the latter, the code is converted into python bytecode which can then be executed by the interpreter. In the former case, it simply takes that bytecode and translates it into the relevant code.

There are many modules that support this including the one you've mentioned. The process of doing so are in the `README.MD` file of the module. My recommendation would be the
[Decompyle++ (pycdc)](https://github.com/zrax/pycdc) as it has worked for me on a number of occasions.

The steps are simple:

**To run pycdas,** the PYC Disassembler: ./pycdas [PATH TO PYC FILE] The byte-code disassembly is printed to stdout.

**To run pycdc,** the PYC Decompiler: ./pycdc [PATH TO PYC FILE] The decompiled Python source is printed to stdout. Any errors are printed to stderr.

Comment: Is it possible to decomyle that code object which has been compiled with python built-in [compile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) function

Comment: @SakibHossain I don't think that's possible, since python doesnt have a built-in `decompile()` function. The `compile()` translates it into AST object which are then evaluated by the `eval() or exec()` function. It is then simply executed

Comment: The answer above is wrong at many levels. Clearly Python can do things above just the run functions that are built in. And the Python decompilers that are written in Python can start with code objects rather that bytecode files. The built-in function `compile()` produces bytecode, not an AST object.